# Relacionamento de Tabelas FluentAPI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Estou tentando fazer um relacionamento de tabelas, utilizando FluentAPI com Entity Framework, na qual o meu propósito são 3 entidades:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public Empresa() 
    {
        this.Gerentes = new HashSet<Gerente>();
    }

    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public string EmpresaNome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Gerente> Gerentes { get; set; }
}

public class Gerente
{
    public Gerente()
    {
        this.Empresas = new HashSet<Empresa>();
    }

    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public string GerenteNome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
}

public class Projeto
{
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string ProjetoNome { get; set; }
}
```

Problema:

Um gerente pode ser gerente em mais de uma empresa, porém um projeto só pertence a um gerente na empresa específica.

Sobre o relacionamento Empresa x Gerente, cheguei a esse resultado:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Empresa>()
    .HasMany<Gerente>(s => s.Gerentes)
    .WithMany(c => c.Empresas)
    .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("EmpresaId");
                cs.MapRightKey("GerenteId");
                cs.ToTable("EmpresaGerente");
            });
```

Agora meu problema é como relacionar o projeto ao gerente, naquela empresa.

Comment: Relacione os projetos a sua empresa e na hora de vincular o gerente ao projeto, valide se são da mesma empresa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o projeto pertence a um gerente em uma empresa específica, eu faria isso:

```
public class Projeto
{
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }
    public string ProjetoNome { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    public virtual Gerente Gerente { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Gerente)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.GerenteId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Projeto>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Empresa)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaId);
```

Eu omiti a **property de navegação** nos métodos `WithMany()` para simplificar, mas provavelmente você criaria um `public virtual ICollection<Projeto>` na classe `Gerente` e na classe `Empresa` e incluiria a **expressão lambda** de acordo nos dois `WithMany()`, embora isso seja opcional.

Entretanto, isso por si só não impede você de atribuir uma empresa que não esteja vinculada ao gerente daquele projeto. Esse controle deve ficar na sua aplicação (ou na sua classe, dependendo de como você trabalhe). Um exemplo simples apenas para dar uma ideia:

```
public class CadastraProjetoRequest
{
    public string ProjetoNome { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public int GerenteId { get; set; }
}

public void CadastraProjeto(CadastraProjetoRequest request)
{
    using(var ctx = new MeuDbContext())
    {
        bool gerenteDaEmpresa = ctx.Empresas.Any(e => e.EmpresaId == request.EmpresaId && e.Gerentes.Any(g => g.GerenteId == request.GerenteId));

        if (!gerenteDaEmpresa)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Essa empresa não possui esse gerente!");

        // criar e salvar o projeto...

    }
}
```

Claro que se é permitido alterar o gerente ou a empresa de um projeto, essa regra teria que ser validada lá também. Se você preferir, você pode criar um método na classe para atribuir o gerente e empresa e validar lá mesmo (daí ficaria encapsulado na classe, e não faria diferença se fosse criação ou alteração). O lado negativo disso, é que você teria que ler o objeto **empresa** do teu `DbContext` fazendo `Include(e => e.Gerentes)` (ou habilitando o *lazy load*), o que iria **custar a leitura de mais dados do banco** (pois a forma anterior usando `Any()` direto no `DbContext` tem uma performance melhor), mas aí cabe a você decidir.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento Alisson, com certeza foi muito útil. Eu estava tendo várias ideias de como fazer, mais com uma ideia diferente com certeza fica melhor. Abs!